# Equivalent to "position_nudge" but with fixed number of pixels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I generated the following ggplot-figure by overlaying a `geom_histogram` with `geom_segment` and moving the `geom_segment` a bit down by using `position_nudge`:

[image]

Now my problem is that via `position_nudge` I have to use the Y-Axis scale as a reference. But what I really want is that the grey-pink-blue bar is just below the zero value of the Y-Axis defined by a fixed amount of pixels (such as in the shown figure).

Because I will generate several of those plots with different ranges of the Y-Axis this approach will place the bar at different positions along the vertical axis (when providing fixed value here: `position = position_nudge(y = -1000)`).

This is my code:

```
tmp_plot <- ggplot() +
geom_histogram(data = comb, aes(x=base, color=orient, fill = orient),
               position="dodge", binwidth = 1) +
geom_segment(data = lines, aes(x = from_v, y = offset_v, xend = to_v, yend = offset_v,
              color = color_v), size = 3, position = position_nudge(y = -1000)) +
cowplot::theme_cowplot() +
scale_color_manual(values=c("steelblue1", "darkgrey", "red", "darkgreen", "hotpink1")) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "darkgreen")) +
theme(legend.position = c(0.35, 0.7), legend.title = element_text(size=10),
      legend.text = element_text(size=10), legend.key.size = unit(0.3, 'cm')) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,100,200,300,387))
```

Comment: I don't think layers in ggplot2 know about absolute values (such as pixels, cm, inches etc). You might have some luck with the [gggrid](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/gggrid/gggrid.html) package.

Comment: The layers do not know about pixels because rendering is done when the ggplot object is printed, and the size and type of graphic output is unknown earlier. One would need to specify the nudge as NPC (native plot coordinates), which I do not think is possible with `position_nudge()`. Your example is not reproducible, because we are missing the data. On the other hand getting this question answered would be very useful...